# Angular promise return "undefined" value .NET MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, promise

In the following sample of code I send a "request" and I am trying to get a response but that returns "undefined" value. 
This is my code so far

```
$scope.SameNameFunction = function() {
            var payload = { itemname: $scope.EventDetails.Name};
            portalRepository.namecall(payload).then(function (payload) {
                console.log(payload.valuesreturned);
                alert("Detected: " + payload.valuesreturned + " events having the same name");
            });
        };
```

Code from the http.post

```
            namecall: function (payload) {
                return $http.post("/Api/PortalData/NameNumberResult", payload);
            },
```

Code from the .cs controller:

```
public ActionResult NameNumberResult(ItemEventNameDTO payload)
{
    var valuetosend = payload.itemname;
    var acf = new AcFunctions();
    var newstorevalue = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(acf.AcConn(), "sp_selectbyname", valuetosend);
    payload.valuesreturned = newstorevalue.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
    return payload.GetSuccess();
}
```

Putting a breakpoint I am getting the appropriate value from the stored procedure, either in .cs and .js files. But while trying to print the message in screen, value do not appear and "Detected undefined events having the same name" is showing instead.
Any help is welcome!

Comment: Can you show the code related to `portalRepository.namecall`?

Comment: @Satpal It is just an http post, I do not think that matters `            namecall: function (payload) {
                return $http.post("/Api/PortalData/NameNumberResult", payload);
            },`

Comment: @Saptal I do not return a promise. In the description I am writing what exactly I want to do with code, I am not sure about the way to do that, but I think that can be implemented via javascript promises

Comment: @GeorgeD I suspect it does matter. I would put it in the code of the question.

Comment: You are returning promise mate, so use it

Answer (score 2):

As you per your code, you are returning [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

```
namecall: function (payload) { 
    return $http.post(url, payload); 
}
```

You need to use the callback method of [`$http.post()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

```
 portalRepository.namecall(payload).then(function(data){
     alert("Detected: " + payload.valuesreturned + " events having the same name");
 });
```